# Bash Regex TimeStamp Matching

Tags: regex, bash, unix, timestamp

Im trying to get unix timestamps from a log file from 5pm-12am.

Here is the command that i tried or currently using.

```
cat test.log | grep 130805"(1[7-9]|2[0-3])"????
```

I would like to get timestamps like the following below :

```
130805223755 
130805213755 
130805173755
```

I cannot seem to get the right pattern match to get the timestamps above. Asking for your assistance tnx in advance.

Comment: you should be surrounding your reg-ex search target with single-quotes on the cmd line, i.e. `grep '130805(1[7-9]|2[0-3])' test.log`.. If you are, please update your question to show that. P.S. (You don't need/want the dbl-quotes in your search target). Good luck.

Comment: In a regex, `.` is any character, and `?` means the the preceding character (or parenthesized pattern) is optional. So change the `?` to `.` and it should be fine. (However, `awk` would let you use `$1 >= 130805170000 && $1 < 13085230000` which would be a lot easier to understand.)

Comment: @shellter: there's nothing wrong with those quotes. TIAS.

Comment: @rici, yes, you're right. I should have said, "if you're going to use single-quotes, be sure to eliminate the dbl-quotes, as I have done in this example". Good luck to all.

Answer (score 0):

I think the quotes are wrong, having ???? outside the quotes will do shell expansion won't it?

This worked for me:

```
grep -E '130805(1[7-9]|2[0-3])\d\d\d'
```

Comment: Re: "having ???? outside the quotes will do shell expansion won't it?": Yes -- filename expansion -- but in Bash, with typical configurations, that expansion will be a no-op unless there are actual files with matching names. So it's bad practice, but IMHO is unlikely to be a problem here.